# [[[1., 2., 3.]], [[7., 8., 9.]]] # a rank 3 tensor with shape [2, 1, 3]

Tags: tensorflow

Can someone explain to me why does this example have a shape of [2,1,3], i just don't see it?

[[[1., 2., 3.]], [[7., 8., 9.]]] # a rank 3 tensor with shape [2, 1, 3]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indentation does wonders:

```
[ # this one contains 2 items
    [ # each of this contains 1 item
        [1., 2., 3.] # each of this contains 3 items
    ], 
    [
        [7., 8., 9.]
    ]
]
```

Thus, shape is `[2,1,3]`